# Devise AJAX user authentication doesn't redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I have a link in my `application.html.erb` file

```
<%= link_to 'Sprzedaż', sell_path, remote: true %>
```

In the controller I authenticate user with `before_action :authenticate_user!`. Below is my `authenticate_user!` method.

```
protected
  def authenticate_user!
    if user_signed_in?
      super
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render nothing: true, status: :unauthorized } 
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, :alert => 'Aby przejść do tej strony, musisz być zalogowany.' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Basically it works correctly if the user isn't authorized. If the user has enabled Javascript it shows nice notification, and if the user hasn't enabled Javascript it shows alert and redirect to `root_path` which is good. The problem is that when the user is signed in and click the link nothing happens. It should redirect to the `sell_path`.

This is my ItemsController

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def sell
    @user = current_user
    @items = JSON.parse(HTTParty.get("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/#{@user.uid}/inventory/json/730/2?l=polish").body)
  end
end
```

This is my ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :steam_informations

  def steam_informations
    @steam = session[:steam]
  end

  protected
    def authenticate_user!
      if user_signed_in?
        super
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js { render nothing: true, status: :unauthorized } 
          format.html { redirect_to root_path, :alert => 'Aby przejść do tej strony, musisz być zalogowany.' }
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please, provide full controller code

Comment: Controller code has been added.

Comment: And now please add controller where you overrided `authenticate_user!` method

Comment: It's ApplicationController. I've added code to the question.

Comment: Wait... Are you trying to redirect user with ajax?

Comment: I think so. I check if the user is signed in using ajax, so redirect have to use ajax too right?

Comment: Any reasons to do it via ajax?

Comment: I didn't find any other method to check if use is actually signed in without reloading page.

Comment: Why you need to do that? Why you not using js frameworks like `ember.js`, `angular`, `backbone` if you need such dynamic functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to override helpers which defined in runtime. This is not how you must to do it.

In your case I recommend you to define for example `authenticate!` method like this:

```
def authenticate!
  return true if user_signed_in?

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render nothing: true, status: :unauthorized } 
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, :alert => 'Aby przejść do tej strony, musisz być zalogowany.' }
  end
end
```

This method will do nothing if user signed in and redirect to root page if user not signed in. Just define this method in `ApplicationController` and then use `before_filter :authenticate!` hook to execute it.

When `before_filter` \ `before_action` method returns false - rails won't execute your action. And if `return true` or just `return` - rails will execute action after hooks like `authenticate!` and render your views. To make it clear I'll show you some examples.

```
class FooController << ApplicationController
  before_filter :dead_hook, only: :index
  before_filter :nice_hook, only: :show

  def index
    # this action will be never executed because dead_hook method returns false.
  end

  def show
    # this action will be executed right after nice_hook method because of 'return true' command in nice_hook method
  end

  def dead_hook
    return false
  end

  def nice_hook
    return true
  end
end
```

Another way to do just like you trying to do - monkey-patch devise helper. You can do it like this:

```
module Devise
  module Controllers
    module Helpers
      def authenticate_user!
        # implement your logic here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here you can check out whats going on in devise helpers:

[Github Devise Helpers source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L110)

Just for clarification: [there is](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L183) no difference between `before_filter` and `before_action`. Feel free to use any of them. `before_action` newer but `before_filter` not deprecated.

Comment: The problem is how to redirect user to the correct page if the user is signed in?

Comment: Just implement method `authenticate!` like I wrote above and check it out. I will append some info about return in this method. Gimme a sec.